# What is the difference between File and Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In New File I can choose empty class but it does not close the project I am working on. As in the title, what is the difference between a file and a project?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I assume you are using Visual Studio, so I added the tag, since the question is about that, rather than the C# language. if you're using a different IDE, please change the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One ore more files create a project and one ore more projects create a solution.

You are probably adding a new file to you're existing project.

Answer (score 2):

Projects are "buildable" things (they have output) and are *composed of* files. Thus, adding a new file has no reason to "close" the project (whatever that means).

When you get far enough, Solutions are "groups" of projects. Adding a new project to a solution doesn't close anything either.

Answer (score 0):

In any IDE, project is a logical collection of different types of files, such as programs, resources, configuration files etc. There are so many different formats for storing the project information on disk such as .xproj, .csproj etc.

A "solution" is a logical collection of projects. A solution can have just one project in that as well. Solution is stored on disk typically by .sln extension by visual studio. In a solution, programmer can specify the build order of the projects, build configurations etc.